# Set postgresql language to english in arch

Tags: linux, postgresql, locale

How can I change postgresql language to english in arch linux? I am polish and my system language is polish but I would like to have postgres output in english. Actualy I have got:

```
postgres=# \d
                      Lista relacji
 Schemat |         Nazwa         |    Typ    | Właściciel 
---------+-----------------------+-----------+------------
 public  | tablename             | tabela    | stanek
```

And want to have

```
postgres=# \d
                      Relations list
 Schema  |         Name          |    Type   | Owner 
---------+-----------------------+-----------+------------
 public  | tablename             | table     | stanek
```

Comment: `LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8 psql -h localhost -U postgres ...`

Comment: thanks! That helped. You could write it as an answer not like a coment

Comment: Not really a programming question; suggested it be moved to **Super User**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change Linux application language individually set environment variable `LANGUAGE` to desired locale before executing it like

```
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
psql ...
```

or just

```
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8 psql ...
```

To set language permanently you can create alias for command at system startup. Add command

```
alias psql='LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8 psql'
```

to your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute in psql:

```
SET lc_messages to 'en_US.UTF-8';
```